# Article Class, A4/a4 "Unused Global Option"

Tags: paper-size

I'm trying to typeset an article.

The document class is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
```

I have also tried:

```
\documentclass[A4]{article}
```

Both yield the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [A4].
```

(or [a4] depending on input).

The document compiles, but produces a letter-size document.
How can I produce an a4 size document?

Comment: The real option is `a4paper`.

Comment: ^^ What @Bernard said. But for it to be effective, you need to add `\usepackage{geometry}` as well. Also, that's not an error. Warnings are not errors.

Comment: @Bernard: If you can mark this as an answer I can select it. This solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real option is neither  `A4` nor `a4`, but `a4paper`. The default is `letterpaper`.

As commented by @cfr, you only have a warning: LaTeX informs it doesn't understand this option: `A4`, and consequently does nothing with it.